# A token visiting primes

Tags: mathematics

Numbers from 0 to 100 are written down on a piece of paper. A token is placed on the number 0. Each turn you can move the token from number $x$ to number $x+3$ or to number $x+5$. What is the most number of primes that the token can visit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Twenty-three primes can individually be reached: 3, 5, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97

However,

> if two primes differ by exactly 2 or 4, then we can't reach both.

So the best we can do is

> fourteen primes: (3 or 5), (11 or 13), (17 or 19), 23, (29 or 31), (37 or 41), (43 or 47), 53, (59 or 61), 67, (71 or 73), (79 or 83), 89, 97

To help look for optimal solutions, here's a spreadsheet showing all the ways to

> form these primes as 3x + 5y for some non-negative integers x and y:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM1lE.jpg

> We start at (x = 0, y = 0), and can only move down or to the right.

Based on this, one example is

> 5, 11, 17, 23, 29, 41, 47, 53, 59, 67, 73, 79, 89, 97

Comment: This is a great answer, well done! I would like to add that there is an optimal algorithm for finding the optimal sequence (or one of them) using dynamic programming. I will leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I would love if you could transcribe some of that image

Comment: https://pastebin.com/3XL6cej1

Comment: @EdMurphy can you [edit] that into the answer? I can't access pastebin.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to add that there is an optimal algorithm for finding the optimal sequence (or one of them) using dynamic programming. I will leave it as an exercise to the reader.

Then dynamic programming you shall have.

> Consider the sequence $a(n)$, where $a$ is the largest number of primes that can lay on a path going to $n$*. $a(n)$ is easy to dynamically calculate: a path must reach either $n-3$ or $n-5$ before reaching $n$, so it can have at most $\max(a(n-3),a(n-5))+[n\text{ is prime}]$ primes on it.
>  Since 2 is unreachable and all steps change the parity of $x$, we can combine steps in pairs to get a formula that can be used on purely odd numbers: $a(n) = \max(a(n-6),a(n-8),a(n-10))+[n\text{is prime}]$.
>  With the initial condition that $a(\text{negative})=0$, we can do this easily by hand.
>  *This only turned out simple because we ignored that a path needed to start from 0. Fortunately, as long as our final path doesn't visit 7, we're in the clear.

> I found this path simply by visiting the positions where $a(n)$ took a new highest value:
>  [image]

Comment: Yep that's the DP I had in mind. Well done. This solution is $O(n*k)$, where $n$ is the number of values and $k$ is the number of different jumps.